# Plotly hovermode=x displays too many values

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, plotly, visualization

The `hovermode='x'` parameter on Plotly (specifically plotly express, which is what I'm using) isn't strict and can get very confusing. For example, I have a dataframe with rows for `date` (which will be the X), `number` (which will be the Y), and `category` (which will be the hue/color, making multiple lines).

If a category has a gap in dates (e.g. category1 has a value for 3/24 but category2 only has values for 3/23 and 3/25), when I hover over the x-value of 3/24, it will show the `number` value for category1 but instead of not showing anything at all for category2 (or showing a 0/nan), it will show the `date` and then `number` value of the closest point. So in this case, hovering on x=3/24 would produce 3 boxes: one (correct) box with the `number` for category1, and two (incorrect) boxes with the `date` and `number` for close category2 points that don't actually have values for 3/24.

In practice, I'm working with a very large, grouped dataset in pyspark, so ideally the categories that don't have data at that date would show a 0. However, not showing a box at all would be acceptable.

I've considered grouping the data and including rows with a count of 0 so that for each date every category has a row, but I couldn't find a way to do it in pyspark and pandas isn't fast enough.

I'm thinking that this must be possible somehow, because using the basic visualizations that Pyspark in Databricks offers works correctly--showing only hover text for categories that are actually present at the x value, and "0" for categories that aren't. The basic visualizations unfortunately only include 1000 rows, though, so they aren't viable.

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

base_categories = ['category1', 'category2']
dates, categories, numbers = [], [], []
for i in range(0, 50):
  dates.append(datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 12, np.random.randint(1, 30)))
  numbers.append(np.random.randint(1, 1000))
  categories.append(base_categories[np.random.randint(0, 2)])
 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dates', 'categories', 'numbers'])
df.dates = dates
df.numbers = numbers
df.categories = categories

df = df.sort_values('dates')

fig = px.line(df, x='dates', y='numbers', color='categories')
fig.update_traces(mode='lines', hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(height=450, width=750, hovermode='x')
fig
```

[image: image of the issue]